# Getting last row doesnt work

Tags: php, mysql, sql, row

I want to get the last row data but it wont show the last row, instead it shows the first row.
im totally. lost on what to do. i hope someone could help. Thanks.

Here is the code:(pastebin)
[link](http://pastebin.com/5HGXYDKu)

Comment: You need to spend a few minutes importing the relevant code, explain what it is meant to do and detail exactly what is not working.  In order for sometime to spend the time analysing and find a solution for your problem, you need to invest some effort into making the question clear and concise. Avoid external links to your question, as they can't provide any future benefit if the link is removed.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the last row, remove the `count()`.  That turns the query into an aggregation query, which you don't seem to want:

```
select topic_subject, view, reply, topic_date, topic_cat, topic_by
from topics
where topic_cat = '$cat_id_1'
ORDER BY topic_id DESC
limit 1;
```

If you want to know the number of rows in the result set without the `limit`, you can use `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS`.

If you want to put the value in the query, you can do it by joining in an aggregation:

```
select cnt.cnt, topic_subject, view, reply, topic_date, topic_cat, topic_by
from (select count(*) as cnt from topics where topic_cat = '$cat_id_1') cnt left join
     topics 
     on topics.topic_cat = '$cat_id_1'
ORDER BY topic_id DESC
limit 1;
```

Comment: if i do that, it breaks my code wherein i want to show all my category's list. if the category doesnt have a topic, by using your fix, the category that doesnt have any topics disappears. here's the code for further understanding:

Comment: You should edit the question and explain what you want to return.

Comment: @iJoshuaHD . . . The revised second answer may be what you want.

Comment: any ideas or suggestions?

Comment: the secong answer didnt work the way i want it to. :/

Comment: Seems like it would show the lsat row to me and if one doesn't exist, you'll still get a count that says `0`.

Comment: the result of your answer 2 doesnt use the last row. have you checked the pastebin link? thank you.